# Multiple regex condition

Tags: regex

I have a regex wherein it doesn't accept 7 consecutive same numbers:

```
/^(?!.*([0-9])\1{6}).*/
```

If I want to add another validation to the above condition, where/how can I add this? i.e, I want to only accept numeric values and limit the maxLength to 15

Comment: It's.: `/(\d{,15})/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` at the end to the pattern for the entire string.

```
/^(?!.*(\d)\1{6})\d{1,15}$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mUx30h/2)

Comment: Tried this one, but its failing 6 consecutive same numbers.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I've added an online demo.

Comment: @PoulBak But `\d{1,15}` only matches numbers.